# $\inf\Big\{\lambda>0:\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq\lambda\|y\|^2,\;\forall\,y\in F\Big\}\geq \sup_{\|y\|=1}\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|?$

Tags: functional-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex Hilbert space $F$.

For $A\in \mathcal{B}(F)$ we set
$$n(T)=\sup\Big\{\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\;:y \in F,\;\;\|y\|=1\Big \}.$$

> I want to prove that
> $$n(T)=\inf\Big\{\lambda>0:\;\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq\lambda\|y\|^2,\;\forall\,y\in F\Big\}.$$

Let $y \in F$ be such that $y\neq 0$. Then
$$\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|=\left|\left\langle A \frac{y}{\|y\|},\frac{y}{\|y\|}\right\rangle^{\vphantom{a^a}}\right| \,\|y\|^2\leq n(T)\|y\|^2.$$
So,
$$\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq n(T)\|y\|^2.$$
If $y=0$, then the above inequality holds and so
$$\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq n(T)\|y\|^2,$$
for all $y\in F$. Hence
$$\inf\Big\{\lambda>0:\;\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq\lambda\|y\|^2,\;\forall\,y\in F\Big\}\leq n(T).$$
I'm facing difficulties to prove that
$$\inf\Big\{\lambda>0:\;\big|\langle A y,y\rangle\big|\leq\lambda\|y\|^2,\;\forall\,y\in F\Big\}\geq n(T).$$

Comment: For any set of reals, the supremum equals the infimum of the upperbounds. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chrystomath I'm sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Take $S=\{|\langle Ay,y\rangle|/\|y\|^2\}$. Then $n(A)=\sup S$, and the question is whether $n(A)=\inf\{\mathrm{upperbounds of\ }S\}$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\ \epsilon>0\ $, and $ y_\epsilon\in F\ $, such that $\ \|y_\epsilon\|=1\ $ and $\ \left|\langle Ay_\epsilon,y_\epsilon\rangle\right|\ \ge n(T)-\epsilon\ $.  Since *every* $\ \lambda\ $ in the set $\ \left\{\lambda>0\,:\, \left|\langle Ay,y\rangle\right|\le \lambda\|y\|^2, \forall y\in F\right\}\ $ must satisfy the inequalities
\begin{align}
\lambda&=\lambda\|y_\epsilon\|^2\\
&\ge \left|\langle Ay_\epsilon,y_\epsilon\rangle\right|\\
&\ge n(T)-\epsilon\ ,
\end{align}
then $\ \inf\left\{\lambda>0\,:\, \left|\langle Ay,y\rangle\right|\le \lambda\|y\|^2, \forall y\in F\right\}\ge n(T)-\epsilon\ $  as well. Since $\ \epsilon\ $ was arbitrary, it follows that
$$
\inf\left\{\lambda>0\,:\, \left|\langle Ay,y\rangle\right|\le \lambda\|y\|^2, \forall y\in F\right\}\ge n(T)\ .
$$